# Find its taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Find the taylor expansion of $$\operatorname{arcsin}2x$$ with center $0$

I can find taylor expansion of small polynomials but I am not able to find the same for an inverse trigonometric function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $2 x+\frac{4 x^3}{3}+\frac{12 x^5}{5}+\frac{40 x^7}{7}+\frac{140
   x^9}{9}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork i doubt it whether he can understand how the answer came

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how to calculate the derivatives of $\arcsin(x)$?

Comment: Try finding first the Taylor series for the derivative $2(1-(2x)^2)^{-1/2}$. Maybe this one you know already, since it is given by the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), composed with $x\mapsto -(2x)^2$ and multiplied by $2$. Then, to get that of $\arcsin(2x)$ you can integrate this series and make sure the constant term is $\arcsin(2\cdot 0)=0$.

Comment: Note that the binomial series give $(1+x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{n}x^n$, where $\binom{-1/2}{n}=\frac{(-1/2)(-1/2-1)(-1/2-2)\dotsm (-1/2-n+1)}{n!}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just to remove it from the list of unanswered questions.**

$\mathrm{Taylor\:series\:of\:function\:f\left(x\right)\:at\:a\:is\:defined\:as:}$
$$f(x)=f(a)+\frac{f^{'}(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f^{''}(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f^{'''}(a)}{3!}(x-a^3)+\cdots $$

Now applying it
$$0+\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\arcsin \left(2x\right)\right)\left(0\right)}{1!}x+\frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\arcsin \left(2x\right)\right)\left(0\right)}{2!}x^2+\frac{\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left(\arcsin \left(2x\right)\right)\left(0\right)}{3!}x^3+\ldots \:$$
$$=0+\frac{2}{1!}x+\frac{0}{2!}x^2+\frac{8}{3!}x^3+\frac{0}{4!}x^4+\frac{288}{5!}x^5+\frac{0}{6!}x^6+\frac{28800}{7!}x^7+\frac{0}{8!}x^8+\frac{5644800}{9!}x^9+\ldots \:$$
$$=2x+\frac{4}{3}x^3+\frac{12}{5}x^5+\frac{40}{7}x^7+\frac{140}{9}x^9+\ldots \:$$